# Shouldn't two consts in mysql for ref be a type const?

Tags: mysql, indexing, constants, ref, explain

I have the following MySQL query

```
explain select item_id from items use index(user_item_id) where user_id=9 and item_id=10000
```

the following is returned

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key             key_len   ref           rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      items   ref     user_item_id    user_item_id    8         const,const   1       Using index
```

How come the type is ref and not const?

user_item_id is a composite index of user_id and item_id.

Answer (score 2):

High Performance MySql describes a ref type lookup as "This is an index access that returns rows that match a single value"

When the word `const` is added it is described as "optimize away parts of the query and turn it into a constant"

So it seems MySQL needs to be able to find the row from the index in the first place

The consts in the ref column mean that mysql could use previous values for looking up things in the index.

Comment: The query has to access some data - ref means that the data was a matched by a single value - the reason it was not const is that mysql cannot optimize it away - it has to access a row - which in turn sets type to ref and not const

Comment: I should add from the `EXPLAIN` your query looks to be very efficient.